# Adding a loop inside an if statement in a Makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I'm trying to write a command which builds either a file that I pass as a flag, or all files.

I have this for now:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find ./src -name '*.c')

FILE?="all"

# Compile source files into object files
compile:
ifeq ($(FILE), "all")
    for file_dir in $(SOURCES); do \
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $($$file_dir:.c=.o) -c $$file_dir \
    done;
else 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ./out/$(FILE).o -c ./src/$(FILE).c   
endif
```

But since I've added the loop, I get this error:

```
$ make compile

for file_dir in ./src/board.c ./src/main.c; do \
        gcc "-Wall" -o  -c $file_dir \
    done;
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

Comment: This is an awkward use of a Makefile. Generally, if you want to compile a specific file you'd `make thatfile`. And if you want to compile everything you'd define an `all` target and `make all`. If you make the `all` target first then `make` will make everything.

Comment: See [Makefile Tutorial By Example](https://makefiletutorial.com/) particularly [the all target](https://makefiletutorial.com/#the-all-target) and [recursive use of make](https://makefiletutorial.com/#recursive-use-of-make).

Comment: You can write a script to build everything, but then there's no reason to use make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments above: this is a bad way to write a makefile.  If you just want to compile every file every time, write a shell script.

But, to explain the error you see:

You have your semicolon in the wrong place:

```
for file_dir in $(SOURCES); do \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $($$file_dir:.c=.o) -c $$file_dir \
done;
```

The semicolon needs to be after the compile command, not after the `done`.  Without a semicolon after the compile command, the `done` keyword is used as an argument to the compiler and then there is no `done` keyword, leading to the shell syntax error you see.

```
for file_dir in $(SOURCES); do \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $($$file_dir:.c=.o) -c $$file_dir; \
done
```

**ETA**

Also, this is wrong: `$($$file_dir:.c=.o)`  You are trying to use a make variable expansion on a shell variable.  That cannot work: all make variables are expanded BEFORE the shell is invoked.

You need something like `$${file_dir%.c}.o`, using shell features.

**PPS**

All your makefile appears to do is compile the files.  Make has built-in rules that know how to do this.  All you have to do is this:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find ./src -name '*.c')

compile: $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
```

That's it.  Make knows how to compile a `.c` file and create a `.o` file, on its own.

Comment: Ok, this makes total sense. I'm new to C (from typescript) so trying to learn how to do all this is HARD! After reading @Schwern 's comment, I'll write separate make files for each file. But thanks for pointing out the issue in my code.